# SimMetalHost process for iOS simulator using 40GB of RAM on Mac

Tags: flutter, macos, ios-simulator, ram

I've been using my 8GB M1 Macbook Air to make a Flutter mobile app. I'm testing it on an iPhone 14 Pro Max iOS simulator. I recently got a popup saying my system was out of application memory. None of the apps I had open seemed to be taking up that much RAM. I checked in activity monitor and found the process `SimMetalHost (iPhone 14 Pro Max: default)` was using around 40GB of RAM. I stopped the process which stopped the simulator. That fixes the error temporarily, but then the issue comes back after an hour or so.

Comment: what is your app about? Maybe it does very heavy task that makes iPhone down

Comment: and run `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: @Nguyenfamily did you assume the app is faulty? It has been stable for quite a while but was upgraded to the latest flutter updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check [issue number 127482](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/127482) at Flutter repository (from May 24, 2023).

Try to downgrade Flutter to an older version (before 3.10) and see if the behavior persists.

Comment: or run with `flutter run --no-enable-impeller`

Comment: Please help upvote the question if you found the resolution for the problem here; which means defaults won’t work in future.

Answer (score 1):

Following can be the possible reasons for the too much memory consumption:

- Using widgets excessively (Each widget seperately consumes memory)
- Complex widgets (widgets with animations)
- Third-party plugins (possibly some third party plugins xan be poorly written)
- Wrong rendering mode (Flutter has two rendering modes, software and hardware. Software rendering is slower, but it uses less memory. Hardware rendering is faster, but it uses more memory.)

For simmetalhost:

- Reduce the size of your images
- Use less animations
- Use less text
- Use a lighter theme

Bonus: Close unused to reduce the risk of swap.

Answer (score 0):

Run your app in Simulator using `flutter run --no-enable-impeller` to fix the memory leaks. This is a open issue on GitHub you can find [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/127482).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34701923)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue when i switched to the master branch. Switching back to the stable branch fixed the issue.